# What is the difference between page.present() and NavController.push()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know the difference between page.present() and navController.push(), this is used when you change pages from ionic, so is there any difference in terms of efficiency, good practice, etc?

I'm using ionic 3.

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the difference between modal pages and the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly confused at the usage of these two methods

1. present() is used when you use modal and popover pages inside your app. present() is used to present the modal/popover from within the component instance.
2. push() and pop() methods is used to manipulate to navigate throughout an app by pushing and popping pages or inserting and removing them at arbitrary locations in history(this is according to ionic official docs)